# WCF SOAP service cannot process the message because it sends multipart message and expects 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, utf-8, multipart

I have a problem with WCF Soap 1.1 configuration. I have created a WCF service with basicHttpBinding. Bellow the configuration. The service is WCF_SOAP_REST_SERVICE.BiasImpl:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave" name="WCF_SOAP_REST_SERVICE.Service">
        <endpoint address="soapService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WCF_SOAP_REST_SERVICE.Service" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServBehave" name="WCF_SOAP_REST_SERVICE.BiasImpl">
        <endpoint address="soapService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp"
          contract="WCF_SOAP_REST_SERVICE.BiasImpl" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
     <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttp" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false" messageEncoding="Mtom" >
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
      maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
     </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServBehave">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I am testing the service using SoapUI. The problem is, that I can test the service if I send small packages. I can test it and debug it with Visual Studio, but when I try to send bigger packages (for example a normal request might contain about 500kb because it will contain several images inside), the request is sent using multipart packages, and the WCF binging is configured to accept 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. So I get this error in SoapUI

```
Fri Apr 24 08:16:31 EDT 2015:DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'multipart/related; type="text/xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; boundary="----=_Part_0_1561749008.1429877791373"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

This is the service interface as generated by svcutil.exe. ( The wsdl is predefined, cannot be changed)

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://my.custom.url/codification/", ConfigurationName="Codification")]
public interface Codification{


.
.
.

    [OperationContract(Action="CheckQuality"/*, ReplyAction="*"*/)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(my.custom.url.CodificationFaultDetail), Action="CheckQuality", Name="CodificationFault")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat()]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(ResponseTemplate))]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(RequestTemplate))]
    CheckQualityResponse CheckQuality(CheckQuality request);

.
.
.

}
```

This is the implementation:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class CodificationImpl : Codification
{
    .
    .
    .

    public CheckQualityResponse CheckQuality(CheckQuality request)
    {
        //implementation goes here
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

CheckQuality class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[MessageContract(WrapperName="CheckQuality", WrapperNamespace="http://my.custom.url/codification/", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class CheckQuality
{

    [MessageBodyMember(Namespace="http://my.custom.url/codification/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable=true)]
    public CheckQualityCheckQualityRequest CheckQualityRequest;

    public CheckQuality()
    {
    }

    public CheckQuality(CheckQualityCheckQualityRequest CheckQualityRequest)
    {
        this.CheckQualityRequest = CheckQualityRequest;
    }
}
```

What do I have to configure in the WCF service binding to accept multipart messages?

Comment: Can you please post on how your WCF method looks like? Also try to set your readerQuota values to something larger than your expected request size.

Comment: I updated my post to include service interface and implementation. Also, included readerQuotas, same error.

Comment: Any specific reason on why you have included the XmlSerializationFormat() on your OperationContract ?? Also can you provide CheckQuality class properties

Comment: It was autogenerated with svcutil. However, if i remove it, it still has the same error

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You have hosted a WCF Service that has a method CheckQuality. From a client app (.NET app or SOAP UI) you are trying to upload a image to this service of size 500KB and you get an exception.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue, the error from SoapUI is explained in the post

Comment: Can you replace your binding with  <binding name="basicHttp" bypassProxyOnLocal="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             useDefaultWebProxy="false" messageEncoding="Mtom" transferMode="Buffered">

Comment: On SOAPUI you have a setting called DisableMultiparts in your request properties. Try setting that to False and see if it works

Comment: No, does not works. Tried DisableMultiparts = true and DisableMultiparts = false

Comment: Also can you tell me on how you are uploading smaller images from SOAPUI.

Comment: I use a groovy script to load data from a file

Comment: Does the script read the file and populate the field information in the request from SOAPUI? Also i did notice that you have set messageEncoding set to "MTOM" on your binding configuration. Can you make sure that the same settings is being used from SOAPUI or try removing that and try

Comment: Yes, the script reads the file and populates the field information in the request. The SOAPUi project should not be changed, because it is the same project for different service implementations (Java, WCF.Net, BPMN) for the same WSDL. I have to create the WCF version of the service, (using the same WSDL contract) and all versions should work with the same SOAPUI project. Both Java and BPMN projects work without problem. WCF works at 10% because of the multipart problem.

Comment: So you are kind of reverse engineering from WSDL, trying to build a WCF service from an existing WSDL. We need to know how the WSDL looks like or how the CheckQuality class looks like i.e. the properties etc it has so that we can help you out

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing. This is the path to the WSDL: http://docs.oasis-open.org/bias/soap-profile/v1.0/os/BIAS.wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below WCF service that works from SOAPUI

Service

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IImageService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool CheckQualityOfImage(CheckQuality objCheckQuality);
    }


    [DataContract]
    public class CheckQuality
    {
        [DataMember]
        public MemoryStream ImageData { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ImageFileName{ get; set; }
    }
```

Implementation for the interface below:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class ImageService : IImageService
    {
        public bool CheckQualityOfImage(CheckQuality objCheckQuality)
        {
            if (objCheckQuality != null)
            {
                if (objCheckQuality.ImageData.Length > 0 && ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(objCheckQuality.ImageFileName))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Web.config on the server

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="noSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                            maxDepth="64" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
          <service name="XMLService.ImageService" behaviorConfiguration="default">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="noSecurity" contract="XMLService.IImageService" />
          </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <behavior name="default">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />      
        </behavior>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now my request from SOAPUI is as shown in the screenshots attached

[image: Success]

[image: Empty request without file]

Make sure to match the request properties in SOAPUI. Some more information on using SOAPUI with attachments can be found [here](http://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html#2-4-Inline-Files)

NOTE: I have made a few assumptions on properties in the CheckQuality class and I have used a 6MB file for upload

Comment: I see you are sending images as an attachment. That's not an option for me.

Comment: The attachments are converted to a stream when the request is sent from SOAPUI

Comment: I use a groovy script to load data from a file.